# sqlMapClient.startTransaction() - cases

Tags: java, mysql, struct, ibatis, sqlmap

Is it possible to use `sqlMapClient.startTransaction();` and  `sqlMapClient.commitTransaction();` in the case of `Select` statements?

I have given start and commit transaction for insert , update and select statement and somewhere I am getting an error.

> MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:
>
> All connection started and closed. and given for each start transactions. Nothing has added in catch block.

```
 finally {
     sqlMapClient.endTransaction();
 }
```

I guess there is no need of using start /commit transaction for select statements. Can anyone please clarify it?

Comment: from the error message, it seems a commit/rollback transaction happens before the select, or another implicit connection close happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error just indicates that the connection already closed, you may missed some exception/errors.

To answer your question, select of course can be in a transaction.

Comment: I have given end transaction both in catch and finally. that was the problem.